# Android mipmap for app icons only

Tags: android, android-studio

Does the mipmap for the application luancher icons only, for example if I'm using an image for a button, should this image go to the mipmap directory too, or to the drawble folders ?

In other words: Does mipmap replace the drawble dir ? Or we should keep in both (mipmap for app launcher icons, and drawble for the rest like image button ...etc) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mipmap is used for app icons and drawables for other assets.

Say you have a device which picks the icon from **drawable-xhdpi** folder for an asset which is used in the app. Now this same device will pick app launcher icon from **mipmap-xxhdpi** folder. The reason is that android system wants to display the launcher icons with more crisp and clear view.

Hope my answer is clear.

Comment: Just to be clear: So mipmap for launcher icons only, and the rest goes to drawbles dirs ?

Comment: Yes correct, as i mentioned android system wants to use higher resolution images only for launcher icons. :)

Answer (score 1):

mipmap folders are only for your app or launcher icon , and drawable are for other assets .